# Slow speed and high latency when downloading multiple small files from azure storage container

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage

I'm trying to download data of azure blob storage container to my machine. It contains of multiple small files, 12-60 KB each. When I use Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer app, it downloads no more than few hundreds of items at once and then halts for tens of minutes before trying to download a next batch.
This makes speed of download roughly less than 3 KB/s, which is quite horrible.

I've also tried using open source npm package to download container files, with similar results.

Is there a way to decrease latency/increase speeds? Or is there a better way do download all container data?

Comment: Can you try it with Cerebrata Cerulean - https://www.cerebrata.com/? Like Microsoft's Storage Explorer, it is also a cross-platform Azure management tool (but it's a paid tool). Disclosure: I am part of the Cerebrata team.

Comment: I really don't think there is any way to speed up download speeds. at least, in my experience - with a similar situation of multiple small files - I could not figure out a way. I think it is just how it is.

Comment: Does your instance and blob storage in same region ? Or you download to local machine ?

Comment: @Jay - not sure what you're implying. Different storage account types have different throughput targets (v1 vs v2). Different tools operate in serial vs in parallel (as well as coding against the REST API / SDKs). The OP hasn't really provided any details other than trying to use a general-purpose tool.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thats right. its possible that in my project I did not experiment with different upload download speeds. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it depend on your (local) machine's network speed. So you can try create a small instance in same region, and download to that instance. It will much faster than your local machine . Then try to archive total files and ftp back to your local machine.

Comment: Good comment, but not really an answer, as we have no idea what is going on w/r/t to the OP's situation.